# Full width video not working

Tags: android, html, css, video

I have a video website [vidz.dundaah](http://vidz.dundaah.com/m/), which mostly showcases YouTube videos however when I access the site on my phone which has a screen resolution of `218 X 211`, the videos have a width of about `80%` and when accessed through a PC the videos are `100%` width. I would like to know whether this is just a problem on my end and anyway to resolve the video width to `100%` across all platforms. Thanks.

```css
.underline {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #565656;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 20px 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
.vida{margin:auto 0px;}

.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    padding-bottom: 65%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.video {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="underline vida">
  <div class="container">
    <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/XGnSx3lF1xQ" allowfullscreen class="video"></iframe>
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think your code is work as well.

Answer (score 0):

changing to this seems to solve the problem, at least on my phone `.vida{margin:auto 1px;}`